# transform Pose - undefined reference to std::chrono::time_point, tf2::doTransform

Tags: ros2, transforms

I'm trying to transform frames using tf2 using ros2 rolling but I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/reading_laser.dir/src/reading_laser.cpp.o: in function `geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >& tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >) const':
reading_laser.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE]+0x5a): undefined reference to `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > tf2::getTimestamp<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: reading_laser.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE]+0x7a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > tf2::getFrameId<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: reading_laser.cpp:(.text._ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE[_ZNK7tf2_ros15BufferInterface9transformIN13geometry_msgs3msg12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEEERT_RKS7_S8_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000000000EEEE]+0xcf): undefined reference to `void tf2::doTransform<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&, geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
```

Here's my callback function

```
 void transform() {

        std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d> temp_pose;
        for (const auto & input_pose : poses_) {
            // transform vector poses into PoseStamped to be compatible with transform function
            geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped input_pose_;
            input_pose_.header.frame_id = "robot_frame";
            input_pose_.pose.position.x = input_pose(0);
            input_pose_.pose.position.y = input_pose(1);
            geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped output_pose;
            try {
            tf_buffer_->transform(input_pose_, output_pose, "world");
            } catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "%s",ex.what());
            }
            //transform output poses back into vector 
            temp_pose.push_back({output_pose.pose.position.x, output_pose.pose.position.y});
        }
        poses_ = temp_pose;
}
```

The error happens in this line

```
tf_buffer_->transform(input_pose_, output_pose, "world");
```

Here's how it's defined in the node

```
tf_buffer_ = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(this->get_clock());
subscription2_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_);
```

This is how the file is configured in my CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(grid_map_core REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(grid_map_cv REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)

add_executable(reading_laser src/reading_laser.cpp 
src/ShaftGrid.cpp)
    ament_target_dependencies(reading_laser rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs grid_map_core tf2 tf2_ros geometry_msgs grid_map_cv OpenCV)
set(targets_list
  reading_laser)

install(
  TARGETS ${targets_list}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

Any idea why this is happening? It doesn't happen when I use other functions such as

```
 tf_buffer_->lookupTransform("world", "robot_frame", rclcpp::Time(0));
```

Comment: Undefined reference sounds like a linker problem. How is your CMakeLists.txt file configured? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Done. But when i use a different function such as lookupTransform instead of Transform with the same configuration, it works fine so I'm not sure why the latter function is causing linking problems

Answer (score 1):

To use type transforms you need to include the appropriate packages + link against them. When you call `doTransform` against a `geometry_msgs`, you have to include the `tf2_geometry_msgs` package headers and link against them to get the implementation. This allows users to create their own `toTransform` functions for various custom types. There's an analog as well for eigen and `sensor_msgs` types you should also be aware of.

https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/49d4be4e8dd08282fc3bf5238459ce41d6befe6f/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did that and I still get a similar error

Comment: Did you link against it too?

Comment: yes I linked it as well